# Package libmysql++-dev is not found in Debian buster/sid

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to install `libmysql++-dev` on my Debian server, but I am getting the below error "Unable to locate the package".

```
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~# apt-cache search libmysql++-dev
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~# apt-get install libmysql++-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysql++-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmysql++-dev'
```

I updated my `/etc/apt/sources.list` as below:

```
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~#
```

I ran `apt-get upgrade` after updating the `sources.list` file, but nothing seems to be working.

The official Debian buster/sid link has the package information https://packages.debian.org/sid/libmysql++-dev.

Below are the OS details:

```
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~#
```

I am not sure how to install the package on my server.

Edited
As mentioned in the comments below, updating the set of outputs after modifying the sources.list

```
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-glib-2.0 libgirepository-1.0-1 libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libpython-all-dev python-all python-all-dev python-asn1crypto python-cffi-backend python-configparser python-crypto python-cryptography python-dbus
  python-entrypoints python-enum34 python-gi python-idna python-ipaddress python-keyring python-keyrings.alt python-pip-whl python-secretstorage python-six python-wheel python-xdg
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~# apt-get install libmysql++-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysql++-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmysql++-dev'
root@rs-dal-karthik-test:~#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repositories only reference Buster, and the `mysql++` set of packages isn’t part of Buster, because the packaging is buggy (see [#871302](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=871302) and [#919377](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=919377)).

[The best practices for testing users](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting#Best_practices_for_Testing_users) recommend configuring both testing (Buster currently) and unstable repositories, so that you can install packages from unstable when they’re not in testing. That does create the possibility that you’ll install buggy software though, as would be the case here.

I wouldn’t recommend running testing on a server, especially just now — testing is frozen in preparation for the next release of Debian, so updates (including security fixes) are liable to take longer than usual to be made available there.

Comment: MySQL++ upstream maintainer here: the portability problem in the first ticket you reference was [fixed and released last July](https://tangentsoft.com/mysqlpp/doc/trunk/ChangeLog.md). As for the GCC issue, that’s up to the Debian package maintainer. It looks like what’s wanted here is an interested package maintainer.

Comment: Sorry @Warren, I didn’t mean to imply that your software is buggy (and I understand how my answer comes across as saying so).

Comment: @StephenKitt, I have updated my sources.list with unstable and testing repositories, still I couldn't get mysql++ packages after "apt-get upgrade", is that something I am missing? I followed the link for best practices for testing users, but it is not working.

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update`?

Comment: @StephenKitt yes I did ran, I specified in my above comment as well. I am updating the question with the recent output of `sources.list` , `apt-get update` and `apt-get install`

Comment: **`update`**, not `upgrade`. Did you run `apt-get update`? You mentioned `apt-get upgrade` in your previous comment and that’s all that appears in your edited question.

Comment: It’s fine not to know the subtleties of `apt-get`, but it suggests that you shouldn’t be running testing/unstable and you’d be better off on stable.

Comment: Also, if you haven’t set up pinning, don’t run `apt-get upgrade` after you run `apt-get update` — you’d end up upgrading all your system to unstable.

Comment: Sorry my bad. okay I got your point. Your solution work for me. I appreciate you for taking the time and explaining it. Thanks